# Connection string connects to wrong database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-connection

I'm trying to develop my first web app. I deployed my app to the server host (SmarterAsp.net) and kept having trouble connecting to my app's database.

I tried connecting to the app database locally (running my app in my Visual Studio with IIS Express) with the smarterasp username and password and it connected to my local database. I even took out the connection string entirely and it still connected to my local database.

I tried connecting to my app database in SSMS to see if I have the wrong user name and password and it worked perfectly fine. I'm at a loss to figure out where I'm going wrong

Here are my connection strings

```
<add name="TimeSheetDbContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=data source.net;Initial Catalog=catalog;User Id=user id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True " 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
<add name="DefaultConnectionEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/VerifyCompanyCeo.csdl|res://*/VerifyCompanyCeo.ssdl|res://*/VerifyCompanyCeo.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=';data source=data source;initial catalog=catalog;integrated security=false;User Id=user id;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework';" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here is my database connection code code in my controllers

```
  private TimeSheetDbContext db = new TimeSheetDbContext();
```

I tried to clear the Visual Studio cache but that too didn't help. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks so much

Comment: What kind of EF are you using - code first or db first? I see two different kinds of connection strings.

Comment: I'm using code 1st I suppose I only need the 1st one

Comment: Is your db hosted on the same server where you have hosted the web app?

Comment: And could you please publish the error message?

Comment: Yes it's on the same server I believe(certainly the same server company). The error message is a 504 message